# JMeter gives "The target server failed" Error

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

We use Jmeter to do performance testing.  I gave 10 threads(10 users) with ramp up time 60 secs, 4 out 10 users failing to logout getting `org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond`

Our script works this way. User logs in, access list page and do one submit operation and access the details page of the submit. Every user does three times and logs out. When I have just one time instead three time it works well, But when I configure the script to do for three times then I face above mentioned error.

Im not really not sure is it some thing related to Jmeter settings or server settings?

Comment: Did you make sure that each user is really unique (e.g. review each login request with View Results Tree)?
Does server show any errors? Does server access log shows this logout request at all?
Are those always the same users or random ones?

Comment: All are unique users and I don't see those requests in nginx access log which is there before the request reaches to application

Answer (score 21, accepted):

disable KeepAlive. worked for me.

Comment: HttpRequest sampler has a checkbox for it

Answer (score 10):

disable KeepAlive worked for me.  Open the http request sampler , there is a check box KeepAlive which is by default selected.

Answer (score 3):

This error is not from Jmeter end.

There may be an issue with one of the following:

- **Network Bandwidth (network cards, interfaces and switches)**
  Monitor your environment
- **Timeout or retries**
  edit the jmeter.properties file for retries = 3 and timeout = 120.

Also you can refer to below link for tuning your jmeter script

- http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have set these properties already as I read this in some other forums
httpclient.timeout=120
http.java.sampler.retries=3

But still no luck

Comment: **Every user does three times and logs out. When I have just one time instead three time it works well, But when I configure the script to do for three times then I face above mentioned error.**

Please clarify on the above point, do you mean the issue occurs when you set **LOOP** settings to 3 ?

Comment: No we haven't set loop settings in Jmeter instead we did the script to do three submits for each user. Even If I give single submit with more number of users I face the same error

Comment: "org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond" 

  from my experience this error is probably confusing since your request might have already got processed on server, it is just that Jmeter did not receive response back from server on time. I would suggest to check application/server logs to find any errors during test execution time frame.

Comment: Please change the **Implementation** to **JAVA** for all HTTP/s requests and run again.

Comment: @JmeterPerfTest : Thanks, I was having the same issue and setting "implementation" to Java fixed it. Why isn't it set like this by default though (and what exactly does this setting do)?

Answer (score 0):

I was running multi threaded high-load tests and increasing the timeout value from 10s to >1 min helped in that case.